# Validation accuracy almost zero while training accuracy much higher

Tags: validation

I am training a large dataset with CNN. The training dataset has 46182 samples and 1414 different classes , while the validation dataset has 14053 samples and 790 different classes.
The first question is about the difference in classes number between the datasets (training and validation). The program does not have an error but I am asking if they can have a different number of classes.
The second question is about the validation accuracy. It is almost zero value. Why ? What is wrong with my data set ? I will add any further detail you need in order to answer this question.
Thank you everybody

```
  Using device: cuda
ConvNet(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(2, 2), padding=(2, 2))
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (3): Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (4): ReLU()
    (5): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (6): Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (7): ReLU()
    (8): Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (9): ReLU()
    (10): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU()
    (12): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(6, 6))
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (1): Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (2): ReLU()
    (3): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (4): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (5): ReLU()
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1414, bias=True)
  )
)

Epoch [1/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 4.3480
Epoch [1/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 2.9175
Epoch [1/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 2.9079
Epoch [1/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 3.1212
Epoch [1/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 3.0263
Epoch [1/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.8653
Epoch [1/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 3.2399
Epoch [1/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 2.6928
Epoch [1/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 3.0468
Epoch [1/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 3.9601
Epoch [1/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 3.0152
Epoch [1/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 2.3946
Epoch [1/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 2.4321
Epoch [1/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 2.2768
Training accuracy is: 47.609458230479405 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.01423183661851562 %
Epoch [2/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 2.3812
Epoch [2/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 3.6333
Epoch [2/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 1.5989
Epoch [2/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 2.0270
Epoch [2/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 2.0203
Epoch [2/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.7256
Epoch [2/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 2.1529
Epoch [2/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 1.8853
Epoch [2/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 1.7869
Epoch [2/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 2.4056
Epoch [2/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 2.2948
Epoch [2/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 2.8236
Epoch [2/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 2.0853
Epoch [2/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 1.4059
Training accuracy is: 61.51097830323503 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.01423183661851562 %
Epoch [3/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 1.5463
Epoch [3/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 1.6350
Epoch [3/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 1.5154
Epoch [3/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 1.3911
Epoch [3/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 2.3427
Epoch [3/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.9637
Epoch [3/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 2.2812
Epoch [3/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 1.3364
Epoch [3/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 1.6822
Epoch [3/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 1.4466
Epoch [3/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 2.2428
Epoch [3/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 1.6200
Epoch [3/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 1.0331
Epoch [3/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 1.2516
Training accuracy is: 64.0465982417392 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.01423183661851562 %
Epoch [4/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 2.8520
Epoch [4/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 1.6832
Epoch [4/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 1.6646
Epoch [4/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 1.5798
Epoch [4/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 1.0860
Epoch [4/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.6025
Epoch [4/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 2.0202
Epoch [4/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 2.2118
Epoch [4/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 2.6608
Epoch [4/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 1.5132
Epoch [4/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 2.2968
Epoch [4/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 1.6361
Epoch [4/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 1.5535
Epoch [4/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 1.9294
Training accuracy is: 65.98891342947469 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.03557959154628905 %
Epoch [5/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 2.3014
Epoch [5/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 1.3139
Epoch [5/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 2.4293
Epoch [5/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 1.4564
Epoch [5/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 1.5917
Epoch [5/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.2819
Epoch [5/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 1.7925
Epoch [5/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 2.0991
Epoch [5/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 1.6835
Epoch [5/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 1.4019
Epoch [5/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 2.3408
Epoch [5/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 1.6424
Epoch [5/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 1.7549
Epoch [5/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 2.1294
Training accuracy is: 67.10406651942316 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.01423183661851562 %
Epoch [6/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 1.5786
Epoch [6/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 1.9251
Epoch [6/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 1.1821
Epoch [6/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 1.7785
Epoch [6/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 1.8077
Epoch [6/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.8270
Epoch [6/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 0.7196
Epoch [6/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 1.3857
Epoch [6/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 1.4348
Epoch [6/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 1.4984
Epoch [6/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 2.2927
Epoch [6/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 1.6183
Epoch [6/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 1.4204
Epoch [6/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 1.9037
Training accuracy is: 68.15858992681132 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.02846367323703124 %
Epoch [7/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 2.4369
Epoch [7/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 1.4145
Epoch [7/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 2.3228
Epoch [7/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 1.0643
Epoch [7/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 1.6115
Epoch [7/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.7311
Epoch [7/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 1.8682
Epoch [7/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 1.9544
Epoch [7/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 1.3249
Epoch [7/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 1.5936
Epoch [7/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 1.8037
Epoch [7/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 0.9030
Epoch [7/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 0.9519
Epoch [7/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 2.1336
Training accuracy is: 69.43614395218917 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.03557959154628905 %
Epoch [8/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 2.6581
Epoch [8/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 1.9336
Epoch [8/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 1.8492
Epoch [8/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 1.5723
Epoch [8/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 1.4108
Epoch [8/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.3323
Epoch [8/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 1.1944
Epoch [8/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 1.4232
Epoch [8/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 1.7826
Epoch [8/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 2.1287
Epoch [8/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 2.4027
Epoch [8/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 1.3423
Epoch [8/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 0.7948
Epoch [8/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 1.5933
Training accuracy is: 70.04677146940367 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.021347754927773428 %
Epoch [9/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 1.2857
Epoch [9/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 0.9126
Epoch [9/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 1.9613
Epoch [9/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 1.1776
Epoch [9/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 0.9943
Epoch [9/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.0764
Epoch [9/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 1.9013
Epoch [9/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 1.6114
Epoch [9/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 1.4612
Epoch [9/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 1.4244
Epoch [9/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 1.8325
Epoch [9/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 1.5229
Epoch [9/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 1.2167
Epoch [9/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 1.9158
Training accuracy is: 70.64873760339526 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.02846367323703124 %
Epoch [10/10], Step [100/1444], Loss: 1.8997
Epoch [10/10], Step [200/1444], Loss: 1.0037
Epoch [10/10], Step [300/1444], Loss: 1.7071
Epoch [10/10], Step [400/1444], Loss: 1.0976
Epoch [10/10], Step [500/1444], Loss: 1.6068
Epoch [10/10], Step [600/1444], Loss: 1.5771
Epoch [10/10], Step [700/1444], Loss: 1.0570
Epoch [10/10], Step [800/1444], Loss: 0.7969
Epoch [10/10], Step [900/1444], Loss: 2.2452
Epoch [10/10], Step [1000/1444], Loss: 1.0465
Epoch [10/10], Step [1100/1444], Loss: 1.3647
Epoch [10/10], Step [1200/1444], Loss: 1.2038
Epoch [10/10], Step [1300/1444], Loss: 0.9818
Epoch [10/10], Step [1400/1444], Loss: 1.5678
Training accuracy is: 71.37845913992464 %
Validation accuracy is: 0.04981142816480467 %
```

Answer (score 0):

Some further details might be needed to answer precisely.

- Are all the validation classes in the training classes?
- Have you tried to resample your datasets (training vs validation)?

It seems like your model overfits but to an extreme degree. Plus, your loss doesn't seem to decrease much over training; is it the training, validation or overall loss?

What comes to mind is that the number of samples per class might be a bit too low (30 for training and 20 for validation). See this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0003267012016479?via%3Dihub) for further insights.

### Edit:

With your answers, I can say there is an inherent formulation issue. You can't expect the model to predict classes it has not seen before. I would recommend you inspect the results deeper, let's say per class or error. And then you should also try resampling (merge and divide), having all classes present in the training dataset.

Comment: No. Not all the validation classes are in/among the training classes.
And what do you mean for resample my datasets? Do you mean to assemble/divide in a different way the training and validation datasets. At the moment they are in a proportion 4 to 1. Should I change this proportion ? As far as concerns the loss it is the training loss.